# Generalization of the well known fact about processes with stationary and independent increments

Tags: probability, expected-value

It can be easily shown that for the process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ which has independent and stationary increments the following holds:
$$
EX_n = nEX_1,
$$
where $n$ is an integer number.

Is this equation true if we replace an integer $n$ by a real number $t$, i.e.
$$
EX_t = t EX_1,
$$
If is it true, how we can prove it?

Comment: If $t$ is real then what is an independent and stationary increment?  Are you saying $X_{a+k}-X_a$ and $X_{b+k}-X_b$ are independent and identically distributed whenever $a \le a+k \le b \le b+k$ ?

Comment: Yes, I understand it as you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X_t)$ has stationary independent increments the the function $f(t)=EX_t$ satisfies the Cauchy equation $f(t+s)=f(t)+f(s)$. If you assume that the process $(X_t)$ is a measurable process you can show that $f$ is measurable and this implies $f(t)=ct$ for all $t$ where $c$ is a constant. Hence $EX_t=ct$ so $EX_t=tEX_1$.

The equation $f(t+s)=f(t)+f(s)$ comes from $X_{t+s}= (X_{t+s}-X_s) +X_s$